# BIOS only shows Manjaro installed usb devices

Tags: boot, usb, bios, uefi, efi

I have a laptop that came with Windows 10 and I wiped the disk to install Arch. But I screwed up on the bootloader or grub stuff (probably) and It didn't boot. So after that I decided to install Manjaro. Everything went well and 1 - 2 months passed. Today I tried to install Pop OS with the same laptop but inside the boot menu I see nothing about my usb drive. After that I also tried with other usb drives with different distros (xubuntu) and also windows but nothing about usb drivers showed up **(different computers and laptops showed all the usb drives)**. I tried to install Manjaro and it's showed up (but I didn't installed it).

I think I damaged something about efibootmgr but not sure.

Here are my current `efibootmgr -v` results:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 2001,0000,0004,2002,2003,0002
Boot0000* Manjaro       HD(1,GPT,5a8f3754-ba72-3847-8bea-adb89fe05f9e,0x1000,0x96000)/File(\EFI\Manjaro\grubx64.efi)
Boot0001* EFI PXE 0 for IPv4 (B4-A9-FC-4B-61-B6)        PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x1)/Pci(0x0,0x0)/MAC(b4a9fc4b61b6,0)/IPv4(0.0.0.00.0.0.0,0,0)RC
Boot0002* Internal EFI Shell    MemoryMapped(11,0x8a913080,0x8b5aa07f)/FvFile(7c04a583-9e3e-4f1c-ad65-e05268d0b4d1)RC...D
Boot0004* EFI Hard Drive (KINGSTON SA400M8240G) PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x17,0x0)/Sata(2,0,0)/HD(1,GPT,5a8f3754-ba72-3847-8bea-adb89fe05f9e,0x1000,0x96000)RC
Boot2001* EFI USB Device        RC
Boot2002* EFI DVD/CDROM RC
Boot2003* EFI Network   RC
```

Thanks :)

---------------------- UPDATE -----------------------
10.09.2021

I tried etcher with Latest **Fedora Workstation, Pop OS** and **Arch Linux**, none of them worked.

I installed ventoy to my usb disk and throw my manjaro and pop os inside it. Ventoy works with my main machine but still it's not works on my laptop.

Here are the information about my ventoy installed usb stick:

```
**********************************************
      Ventoy: 1.0.51  x86_64
      longpanda admin@ventoy.net
      https://www.ventoy.net
**********************************************

Ventoy Version in Disk: 1.0.51
Disk Partition Style  : GPT
Secure Boot Support   : YES
```

Comment: Is the drive with the Pop OS installer configured to boot in UEFI mode?

Comment: I write the iso with ```dd if=pop_os.iso of=/dev/sdc status=progress```. I also tried a new one with the rufus and it's sad something like "ISOHybrid image detected: The image you have selected is an ISOHybrid, but its creators have not made it compatible with ISO?File copy mode. As a result, DD image writing mode will be enforced." but I did it and it also not worked. **(I used rufus with dd mode for Manjaro so I think yes using UEFI mode)**

Answer (score 0):

Recently help with the Manjaro forum I fixed my problem using Ventoy. I configured Ventoy for MBR and now I can use any iso with my laptop.

Manjaro forum topic:
https://forum.manjaro.org/t/bios-only-shows-manjaro-installed-usb-devices/82034

Ventoy tool I used to fix my problem:
https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).